# How do I resolve 'name xxx is not defined' error

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to follow instructions in this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/image-detection-from-scratch-in-keras-f314872006c9

I am able to set it up with my own images up to this point:

```
def read_and_process_images(train_images):
    X = [] #images
    Y = [] #labels

for image in train_images:
    X.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image, cv2.imread_grayscale), (nrows, ncolumns), interpolation=cv2.inter_cubic)) #read the images
    #get the labels
    if 'Pass' in image:
        Y.append(1)
    elif 'Fail' in image:
        Y.append(0)

return X, Y
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-cb61405b8d99> in <module>()
      4 
      5 for image in train_images:
----> 6     X.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image, cv2.imread_grayscale), (nrows, ncolumns), interpolation=cv2.inter_cubic)) #read the images
      7     #get the labels
      8     if 'Pass' in image:

NameError: name 'X' is not defined
```

Not sure where I need to go from here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing indentation: your `for` loop is outside the function scope, so you need to indent all that block of code

Comment: Thank you very much! Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Python cares about indentation for its code blocks, it is seeing your `for` loop as a separate code block outside of your function. If you indent everything from your for start until the return it should be fixed.